# Remove Main Folder Name from URL in Codeigniter via htacess

Tags: php, xcode, codeigniter, .htaccess

I installed the **Codeigniter** in the folder and site is running from the folder.

Installation folder is 2019

**For example:** `domainame/2019/`

**Detail Page url is:** `domainname/2019/content/postname`

But i want the URL structure like  just need hide the name of folder of the URL

post should be open after that

**Detail page url is:** `domainname/content/postname`

it should not effect main folder

Please give me any solution for that

Comment: you are currently working in a local or server?

Comment: i am working online on linux server

Comment: check the answer and upvote if helpful for you.

Comment: please read my comment

Comment: you cannot hide project name.you can reduce url by changing controllers and methods with the help of routing.

Comment: 1: No need to change htaccess if 2019 is your project name then you can simply move your whole code to server main directory.

2 : if 2019 is not your project name then you can use `route` for that.

Comment: how can i reduced the by changing the URL controllers method, give me proper example

Comment: i can't move the files on main directory coz i want run the files from folder 

but i don't want show folder name in the url 

so please tell me answer according to that

Answer (score 0):

You could use URLREWRITE, or Mod_Rewrite, to do this (Assuming you use URL Parameters).

Eg using pattern `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` with subsistution URL `2019/index.php?{R:1}={R:2}`
would convert `domainname/2019/index.php?content=postname` to `domainname/content/postname`

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html for more details on how to do this on Linux/Apache via .htaccess

Comment: i used this one RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  2019/$1/$2 [L,NC,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /domainame/2019

RewriteRule ^$ /domainame/2019/index\.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|repository|favicon\.gif)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond $1 !^(images.*.(bmp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|pdf|rtf|txt|zip|rar|odt))
RewriteCond $1 !^(images.*.(BMP|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG|DOC|DOCX|XLS|XLSX|PPT|PPTX|PDF|RTF|TXT|ZIP|RAR|ODT))

RewriteCond $1 !^(images.*.(WEBM|AAC|M4A|F4A|MP3|OGG|OGA|OGV|FLV|MP4|M4V|F4V|MOV))
RewriteCond $1 !^(images.*.(webm|aac|m4a|f4a|mp3|ogg|oga|ogv|flv|mp4|m4v|f4v|mov))

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domainame/2019/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

> Assume *domainame* is a folder